# How to use jQuery html() function?

Tags: jquery

When I do this:

```
$('.myDiv').html("<strong>Hello World</strong>");
```

The output inside myDiv is literally:

```
<strong>Hello World</strong>
```

instead of Hello World simply being bolded. Is there any way to use html inside the html() function or a similar function that actually translates html instead of showing it literally?

### EDIT

oops I just realized the above code actually does work. My problem was I am trying to replace the contents of a textarea with html inside and that echoed out the html because that's what happens when you put html inside a textarea anyway. So nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you're not using `.text()` ?

`$('.myDiv').html("<strong>Hello World</strong>");` [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9wPB/1/).

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9wPB/1/).

Answer (score 0):

It will display Hello World in bold when the browser actually renders the HTML. You must be using Firebug or a similar tool to inspect the contents of the `div` you modified. Tools like that don't render the content you are trying to inspect the way the browser would; that's the whole reason you are inspecting the markup. If they did render what you were trying to examine, well, that would just be cruel.

Comment: He said the **output** is `<strong>Hello World</strong>`

Comment: I don't think that's what he is saying. I think he is trying to inspect the result using a debugging tool and is surprised that the tool is not rendering the content. `html()` doesn't look much like `text()` so I don't think he is mixing the two up.

Comment: So what you're saying is that he's expecting the text to be bold inside the Firebug source?

Comment: Yes that's what I  was expecting. However, the asker has added a clarification: `My problem was I am trying to replace the contents of a textarea with html inside and that echoed out the html because ...`  Ok, so it's not a debugging tool he was using, but he was still using `html()`. Similar mistake though.